# How did the power source of Mar-Vell's aircraft end up with her?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

How did

> the Tesseract end up with Mar-Vell

according to the MCU?

And also,

> as Howard Stark found the Tesseract under water in *Captain America: The First Avenger*, why did Fury not have any knowledge of the Tesseract?

Comment: Presumably she was merely the latest in a long line of American scientists to lay hands on it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> So, official Tesseract timeline:
>
> **Captain America: The First Avenger**
>
> • hidden for thousands of years in Asgardian mural, uncovered by Red
>   Skull
>
> • burned through hull of plane, fell into ocean
>
> • recovered by Howard Stark soon afterward, taken into possession by
>   Strategic Scientific Reserve, later to become SHIELD
>
> **Captain Marvel**
>
> • given to Dr. Wendy Lawson to research for Project PEGASUS, a secret
>   multi-billion dollar SHIELD research project. she was secretly
>   Mar-Vell, a rogue Kree secretly using the tesseract to build a secret
>   lightspeed engine to secretly save the Skrulls. secretly.
>
> • kept on Mar-Vell's ship in orbit above earth, used to power
>   lightspeed engine
>
> • in SHIELD's possesion after being swallowed by Goose, vomited onto
>   Fury's desk
>
> •**The Avengers**
>
> • presented to Dr. Selvig to research just before The Avengers
>
> • incorporated into portal machine, used by Loki to open portal for
>   Chitauri
>
> • after Loki's defeat, used to transport Thor and Loki to Asgard,
>   kept in Odin's vault
>
> **Thor: Ragnarok**
>
> • stolen from vault by Loki while he was there to summon Surtur to
>   cause Ragnarok
>
> • on Asgardian escape ship on path to Earth
>
> **Avengers: Infinity War**
>
> • taken by Thanos, breaks casing to expose Space Stone, incorporates
>   into Infinity Gauntlet
>
> • used for The Snap
>
> • chilling on the back of Thanos's hand on a farm somewhere
>
> **Avengers: Endgame**
>
> - Got destroyed by Thanos.

Link - [by u/the_infinite](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/ayi0kt/the_official_captain_marvel_discussion_megathread/ei1u99g)

As to the question of why Fury didn't know, can be because he wasn't the SHIELD director at that time. Just an agent with lower clearance level apparently.

Comment: "chilling on the back of Thanos's hand on a farm somewhere" love it

Comment: “given to Dr. Wendy Lawson” — unless there's an interview somewhere stating this, I don't think it's established, although it seems the most likely option.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite She had the assistance of Skrulls, they could have very easily assumed the identity of whoever had clearance of the Tesseract and stolen it for her.

Comment: @adickinson: I'm not sure about “easily”. They'd have to work out who had clearance for the Tesseract in the first place. Plus assuming identity requires, dare I say it, talent.

Comment: Thalos managed to assume Fury's boss with little trouble, I understand that that was necessary for the story but it demonstrates they had knowledge of who to target for an infiltration, especially if they had someone like Mar-Vell to assist them.

Comment: Project PEGASUS is also the name for SHIELD's project in Thor and Avengers were they are experimenting on the Tesseract, indicating this is just the code name SHIELD uses for researching that blue cube.  Dr. Lawson wouldn't need to steal it, she became the head researcher for the project (or some other higher-up) and presumably had almost unlimited access to it. SHIELD likely thought it was destroyed in the prototype jet that crashed.

Comment: Yep Fury was merely a Level 3 agent at the time of Capt. Marvel (as seen on his S.H.I.E.L.D. ID badge seen in the movie), and from the AoS show we know that's barely clearance enough to read the manual for the coffee machine.

Comment: I think also the implication of the end-credits scene is SHIELD thought it was lost until it came into Fury's personal possession. Who knows what he did with it before giving it to Selvig; it's not clear if he immediately surrendered it to SHIELD or held onto it until it was expedient for him.

Comment: Is really PEGASUS from CaptainMarvel the same as project P.E.G.A.S.U.S??? What I remember from the movie is that PEGASUS was an Air Force-NASA joint operation, and SHIELD seemed to be entirely out of it: Fury needed clearence and there wasn't a single SHIELD Agent or Scientist around.

Comment: As is [stated here](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Project_P.E.G.A.S.U.S.), PEGASUS wasn't SHIELD before 1989... can anyone with canon sources confirm this?

Comment: So when you say "official", you mean "thing I found on Reddit"?